Filament and Tenancy for Laravel FileUpload not saving files in right location
I'm using Tenancy for Laravel (v3.8.2) and Filament (v3.1.47) to create a multi-tenancy application. I have a decent amount of the application working well using different domains for the different applications. However, I have started looking to try and have the users upload files, but I'm having some trouble.
When I upload a file as a user I'm getting the following error Unable to retrieve the file_size for file at location: livewire-tmp/40LsuTIsnBtUsTOvGIrcpexFpm0Y2T-metaYWZsb2dvLnBuZw==-.png..
I can see that Filament uploaded the file to this location storage/app/public/livewire-tmp/40LsuTIsnBtUsTOvGIrcpexFpm0Y2T-metaYWZsb2dvLnBuZw==-.png, but I don't think that's where the file is supposed to go, I believe it's supposed to go tenant1/app/..., which I'm guessing is why it can't check the file size.
Hopefully, this is an obvious fix for someone who has already done something similar, though my colleague and I have been trying to figure this out, and we are clearly missing something. I would appreciate any suggestions.
The below are what I think the relevant code snippets are, but let me know if there's another that people think will help identify the issue.
app/Filament/App/Resources/TenantProjectResource.php
 return $form
    ->schema([
        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
            ->required(),
        Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('image')
            ->image()
            ->label('Project Default Image')
            ->disk('public')
            ->columns(1)
            ->directory('projects')
            ->moveFiles()
            ->maxSize(2048)
            ->columnSpanFull(),
    ]);

config/tenancy.php
'bootstrappers' => [
        //Stancl\Tenancy\Bootstrappers\DatabaseTenancyBootstrapper::class,
        Stancl\Tenancy\Bootstrappers\CacheTenancyBootstrapper::class,
        Stancl\Tenancy\Bootstrappers\FilesystemTenancyBootstrapper::class,
        Stancl\Tenancy\Bootstrappers\QueueTenancyBootstrapper::class,
        // Stancl\Tenancy\Bootstrappers\RedisTenancyBootstrapper::class, // Note: phpredis is needed
    ],

config/filesystems.php
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],


Did you find a solution for the problem? I have the same behavior under Laravel 11.9 / Filament 3.2 / Tenancy 3.8 ..

Have you found a solution for this issue? I’m experiencing the same behavior with Laravel 11.9, Filament 3.2, and Tenancy 3.8.
